# Why doesn't the broswer read the font correctly?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm doing a HTML/CSS project. 
I'm using @font-face to give the browser a series of old-looking font.
When I test the page in my local environment (my PC: IE, Chrome and Mozilla) the font for the initial character works.
When I put it online on the Github hosting service, it doesn't work. The first Character appear as a modern one.
I know that the problem is the font and not the CSS first letter selector because all other CSS declaration about it works well. (padding, color etc...)

I tried to change the font name multiple times, reducing it to a single word as value of "font-family", I tried to remove quotes from the value of font family, I tried to change name to a longer name with quotes.

This is the code in the github repository

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "initial_letter";
    src: url(font/humanistic/initial.ttf),
         url(font/humanistic/initial.eot);
}
```

and this is the one in the local directory:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "initial_letter";
    src: url(font/humanistic/initial.ttf),
             url(font/humanistic/initial.eot);
}
```

They are equal so I don't understand the problem.

I expect to see and old looking letter as first letter.
This is the Font I'm trying to use:

https://www.fontspace.com/house-of-lime/genzsch-initials

Edit: I am using also other fonts inside the page, they are working and their path is written in the same way as this one.

Comment: `font/humanistic/initial.ttf` is a local path. I'm not sure that works with github hosted pages. But if it does, then only if you also uploaded the font file. Did you? You can also try `./font/humanistic/initial.ttf` and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: The problem is with the path

Comment: Without seeing original code nothing can say but suggest you to use fonts `.woff` or `.woff2` format. Convert online `ttf` to `woff` or `woff2` and check again.

Comment: I am using also other fonts inside the page, they are working and their path is written in the same way as this one.
Also in my github repository there is the same structure.

Comment: Are you sure that specific font is licensed for web font use? That could be the difference between it and the other fonts (again, not knowing what those other fonts are or anything else about how you are set up is limiting us to guessing here...).

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey the problem was the web license. I didn't see the license some days ago.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you have to watch out for with fonts and the web is licensing. Fonts must be licensed for use on the web. Sometimes it will work while you're browsing on localhost, but then as soon as you use a "real" host, the licensing check kicks in and your font fails to load. The fact that only one of your fonts is failing to load leads me to believe that this is the problem.

Unfortunately, the FontSpace site your font comes from does not explain about the special needs for hosting fonts for use on the web. There are a number of articles about how licensing works. [This article on Aeolidia is one of the better ones I've read](https://aeolidia.com/understanding-webfont-licensing-structures/).